# Get the image path in ajax and delete that image in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel 5.4 in my project i displayed my images inside  source file
in laravel blade it shows the image correctly..

```
 <div  id="dis_img">
                    @foreach($detail_dir_imgs as $detail_dir_img)
                      <img src="{{ asset($detail_dir_img) }}" height="230" width="200" id="pro_img">
                      <span class="del_proimg">X</span>
                    @endforeach
                  </div>
```

Now i get the image src attribute inside the del_proimg click function which means i want to delete the image when i click this id  and the code inside my click function is

```
$('.del_proimg').click(function(){
      var img= $('#pro_img').attr("src");
      alert(img);
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/deleteimg',
        data: {'img':img},
        success: function(data){
          console.log("ajaxdata",data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
          console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
```

When the id is clicked it get the imagepath and pass the data to controller everything worked fine but in my controller when i try to delete the image path it doesnot delete the image and my controller code is

```
  public function deleteimg(Request $request){
            $img =$request->img;
            @unlink(public_path( $img));
            return Response::json([
              'message' => $request->img
          ], 200);

        }
```

Is this is correct i tried this also `File::delete($img)` but its not delete my image in my folder but no error shows please anyone help me to fix this isssue

Comment: Maybe file-access rights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing entire image source to function deleteimg as `$img`. Just sent image name .Then use `unlink(PATH TO YOUR IMAGE "/" IMAGE NAME)`.
Like you may save the image in `puplic/uploads` then use `unlink(public_path().'/uploads/'.$imageName);`

Comment: yeah thank you but how i get the image name alone in jquery

Comment: You can use the currrent $img as it is .Just explode the $img by "/" and get the last array element.

Comment: can you give me the code i doknow how to use explode function

Comment: $img = "aaa/bb/a.jpg";
$imgArray = explode('/',$img);
$imageName = $imgArray[count($imgArray)-1];
echo $imageName;

Comment: by using explode('/',$img) it split the array now how i get the last element

Comment: $img = "aaa/bb/a.jpg";
$imgArray = explode('/',$img);

//Gets last element,
$imageName = $imgArray[count($imgArray)-1];

Then unlink,
unlink(public_path().'/'.$imageName);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144468/discussion-between-nithin-john-and-karthiga).

Comment: my image under this directory uploads/products/images/id so i gave like this?? unlink(public_path().'/uploads/products/images/'.$id.$imageName);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
unlink(public_path().'/'.$img);
```

this work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Just send image path through ajax call. This will return true if file is deleted. And check your route as well in web.php file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function deleteimg($file_path){
      Storage::delete($file_path);
      return response()->json(array('success' => true));
}
```

Comment: it working I found whats the problem but i doknow how to get the solution when i return my $img variable it shows like this `Object {message: "http://birdys.app/uploads/products/images/50/11474…M-Unisex-Table-Covers-9731474522719404-1_mini.jpg"}` in my console window but when i try to remove that "https://birdys.app" it working correctly

Comment: Any other problem than file delete ?